# Library style app in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am planning to develop my first app in Cocoa. I have been collecting ideas for the UI and have settled in with the design very similar to iPhoto (i.e. library style or 'shoebox' application as referred by Apple's programming guide). In a nutshell I need master detail kind of setup like in iOS (iPad's `UISplitview`).

1. To achieve this should I put a `NSSplitview` and on the left panel have a `NSTableView` and on the right panel have a `NSCollectionView`?
2. Are there any examples/boilerplate or tutorials for creating app in OS X?

Answer (score 1):

Your instincts are correct. You might decide eventually you want something more customizable that an NSCollectionView, but it’ll get you started fast and you can do most of what iPhoto does with it. (You can’t do rows with varying #s of items on them, like Delicious Library does, unless you write your own view.)